# To what extent does Arcane Lock spell reinforce a door from being broken?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

A Wizard casts Arcane Lock upon a door. The spell description explicitly says that the spell will make it "more difficult to break":

> While affected by this spell, the object is more difficult to break or force open; the DC to break it or pick any locks on it increases by 10.

How difficult would it be for the bad guys to break the door? "DC increases by 10" mechanic is irrelevant, since DMG operates AC and hit points for breaking objects (see DMG page 246, "Objects"):

> For the purpose of these rules, an object is a discrete, inanimate item like a window, door ...
>
> When time is a factor, you can assign an Armor Class and hit points to a destructible object.

Here is a relevant question - [Does Arcane Lock Make An Object More Resistant to Damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67757/) - but its answer only describes a trivial fact that RAW the Arcane Lock spell doesn't change the object's HP or AC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Breaking a door in this sense refers to breaking the locking mechanism and forcing it to open. You are not trying to damage the structure of the door, but the lock actually. It is in line with this that the PHB lists this as an ability check and not an attack:

> Other Strength Checks [..] Force open a stuck, locked, or barred door
>   (p. 175-6)

This is what *arcane lock* protects against. It does nothing if you just try to hack it to bits as the answer you reference also points out.

Comment: To add to this...a Strength Check can breach a door in a single Action by 'kicking it down' (which breaks the lock). Attacking the door may take several hits to fully destroy it. A sturdy wooden door could have AC 15 and 18 or more HP. At the DM's discretion it might also have Immunity to Piercing Damage and Resistance to Slashing damage. It could take a fair amount of work to take that door down. Or you could make an Athletics check to deliver a kick to the door and try to smash the lock apart in a single go.

Comment: Why kick it down when you can just use your [ARMPIT POWAAA](https://i1.wp.com/shaneplays.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/advanced_dungeons_and_dragons_dd_players_handbook_2nd_edition_revised.png?resize=377%2C499) @guildsbounty